# running a hive query via cli with columns containing special characters

Tags: bash, hive

I'm writing a bash script, and have to go through a lot of tables with a lot of columns containing special characters ( mainly spaces )
I want to change them with underscores and I have this code so far:

```
while read column;do

    beeline  -e  "use DB; ALTER TABLE X CHANGE `${column}` ${column// /_} STRING;"

done < ./file_with_column_names.txt
```

I wrap the column name in back-ticks and everything should work but I get an error, regardless if the column the script is trying to change has special characters or not:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:49 cannot recognize input near '<EOF>' '<EOF>' '<EOF>' in column type (state=42000,code=40000)
```

However, same query ran from HUE ( obviously the bash variables replaces with column names) works fine.

I don't know why the beeline query fails. Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I discovered the reason. The backticks are also interpreted by BASH, so i need to escape them also like so

```
\`${column}\`
```